# ImportError for graphics.py

Tags: python, import, module, pyzo

I've searched this and couldn't find an answer. I do have the init file. The screenshot attached sums everything up.

[image]
[image]

Added a new screenshot, getting the same error even though all three scripts are in the same Pyzo folder.

Comment: Please try and sum everything up using words rather than just taking a screenshot.

Comment: @khelwood What else is there to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was clicking "Run file" which kept causing this error, simply clicking "Run file as script" does it with no error. Everything was in the right location, I just had to run it as a script. I don't know what this means though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download this [link](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) then put it in same folder and try.

Comment: Same error, I think it's the same file I originally had. Either way, getting the same error. They're all in the same folder, as shown above.